# How do i get the value of an HTML element in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

How do i get the value of an html input element in my component class?

For example, i want to get the username from this input element in my component class.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s12">                  
          <input id="username" type="text" class="validate" name="username">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then i need the value in my component class:

```
export class HomepageComponent {
     username = username;
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html How about using ngModel? :)

Comment: Yes, i have been researching about ngModel, but i couldn't wrap my head around the appropriate binding to use.  @ajt-82

Comment: I'd suggest you actually take a look at the tutorial. You got an answer, yes, but if you look at the tutorial you'd get the hang of the basics. Start here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ngModel` directive there (two way binding) or `template` variable which will help you to hold DOM.

```
<input id="username" type="text" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userName" name="username">
```

**OR**

```
<input #usernameInput type="text" class="validate" 
   name="username" (input)="username = usernameInput.value">
```

Comment: so i did this earlier but my problem is how to access that variable in the component class.

Comment: You could use `this.username` in component class?